# Problems accessing SVN credentials in keychain on macOS v10.12 (Sierra) using Subclipse

Tags: macos, svn, subclipse

When using multiple Eclipse application installations, I am no longer able to access Subversion credentials in the keychain from additional Eclipse applications after upgrading to macOS v10.12 (Sierra). Something seems to have changed on Sierra in OS handling of application identification for keychain access.

Configuration: Eclipse v4.6 (Neon) - two Eclipse.app installations for managing different sets of plugins and workspaces. Subversion 1.9 ([Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_management_software%29) installation). The SVN client configuration has default authentication settings and stores/accesses credentials using the Mac keychain. Originally set up on OS X v10.11 (El Capitan) - SVN operations from command line working, both Eclipse applications triggered prompts to allow keychain access that was granted; both javaHL and SVNKit used from various workspaces, all good.

[Additional configuration note: the eclipse.app copies are *not* installed in the Applications folder - my Eclipse installations are maintained under a separate directory on the boot drive where I manage development tools and workspace launcher helper scripts]

After upgrade to macOS 10.12 (Sierra), with no other changes in the system, command line SVN still works and one of the eclipse.app installations triggered prompt to grant keychain access and working as expected with no further credential prompts. Running the second eclipse.app installation did *not* get a prompt to allow keychain access and always goes straight to a password dialog. Using the save checkbox in the dialog seems to work only for duration of current session; next time that Eclipse application is run, the password prompt is displayed again, so any workspace used from the second Eclipse installation is no longer able to access keychain credentials.

Using Keychain Access to check the SVN credentials item verifies SVN, and Eclipse show up as applications permitted to always access the item. Manually adding a reference to the second eclipse.app installation that is no longer able to access the item does not solve the problem - I am still getting a password prompt on any repository access, so macOS is apparently no longer distinguishing the two different eclipse.app copies as different applications under macOS v10.12 (Sierra).

Attempts to resolve, including rebuilding Subversion; installing a third clean eclipse.app (I tried a 4.7 RC to be different than the two 4.6 copies currently in use); explicitly add multiple Eclipse references to the SVN keychain item using Keychain Access; deleted the SVN keychain item so it was recreated fresh on 10.12. None of these work.

The only solution currently found that allows additional eclipse.app installations to access keychain is to use Keychain Access and change the access control setting from the standard "Confirm before allowing access" with the list of applications specifically granted access to "Allow all applications to access this item".

This isn't a particularly satisfactory resolution and is a significant degradation relative to previous versions of OS X/macOS - having to reenter SVN credentials every time a workspace is used is pretty much unusable. The best theory so far is that the problem seems to be associated to some change on macOS v10.12 (Sierra) with how applications are identified for keychain access; possibly related to path randomization such that application location no longer distinguishes multiple copies of application with same underlying bundle id (?)

Comment: Shouldn't you tag this with OSX related tags to reach the right audience that might have ideas? It seems like you have covered this pretty well from user perspective.

Comment: Good suggestion Mark Phippard - osx tag added. thanks.

Comment: FWIW the symptom shows up in subclipse and is quite baffling/frustrating to users at that level, and over the years people have run into variations of this problem with accessing/storing svn credentials while using subclipse, but I think the source of the difficulty I'm seeing now on Sierra is coming from osx/macos changes in 10.11 and 10.12 and the repackaging of the eclipse distribution for mac that was done in the Eclipse 4.5 Mars release to deliver a "proper" signed eclipse.app bundle

Comment: None of this is controllable by Subclipse. It is just running SVN API and how the keychain works is solely determined by OSX.  I doubt that the native SVN API which is what uses the Keychain API could even do anything to impact the behavior here.